# SQL Server 2008 to 2012 Message 402 The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

The below query

```
 DATEDIFF(minute, b.orig_date + CONVERT (time, b.orig_tm), 
 b.completed_dt + CONVERT(time, b.comp_tm)) AS Time_In_Minutes
```

works OK in SQL server 2008 but in SQL server 2012 it provides the following error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour was corrected in 2012 - If possible convert to DATETIME instead of TIME else use DATEADD()

Comment: Thanks Alex much appreciated!

Comment: Ouch that doesn't work after all... I provides minus results where in 2008 there are none. Could you provide an example of date add please? Thanks